# ASP.NET MVC Razor Helper with @HTML in App_Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I try to make a Helper inside App_Code in cshtml File.

```
// Using's are needed to ensure helpers function correctly.
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
@using System.Web.Mvc.Routing;
@using System.Web.Mvc.Razor;
@functions {
    private static WebViewPage page { get { return PageContext.Page as WebViewPage; } }
    private static System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic> html { get { return page.Html; } }
    private static UrlHelper url { get { return page.Url; } }
    private static dynamic viewBag { get { return page.ViewBag; } }
}

@helper HelperName(Func<dynamic, dynamic> expression)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => expression, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => expression, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => expression)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I don't know if that is possible. I have some errors:

- @Html don't know LabelFor, but i put the using on top
- Maybe Func as parameter is wrong

Comment: This is possible, check this answer how to use the Html helper in your helper method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12826750/1708859

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You could write a normal HTML helper with `@Html.LabelFor` because that your view is strongly typed .The typed `@Html.LabelFor` will generate your lable for you. This is usually just the property name but for properties of complex type and it will allow you to use compile time checking.

you can do some thing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858102/how-can-i-use-an-htmlhelper-inside-a-custom-htmlhelper/43861317#43861317) answer.